# Have the system choose a random unsolved question

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I would like to have random unsolved problem buttons on Stack Overflow. I think that if this feature were enabled on Stack Overflow, it would give benefits to all the users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This already exists: click on the [Unanswered button](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged) and randomly select one of the 7827 pages of unanswered questions.

Comment: Oh Wow, I didn't recognize that button, thanks for the info

Comment: I think one should qualify here: One of the unanswered questions *with one of your favorite tags*

Comment: @YiJiang's独角兽 I see a bunch of questions with my ignored tags on them when using that link.

Comment: @YiJiang's独角兽 That's one tab under Unaswered: check out the other tabs (like "newest" or "votes").

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Stack App](http://stackapps.com) that does this: [Dice Stack - Find a random question](https://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question)